# Oracle 19c / Rman-10038: Database Session For Channel channel_name Terminated Unexpectedly

Tags: oracle, restore, rman, oracle-19c

I am getting this error while database restore.
This is the first time such an error has been getting from a process that has had no problems for a long time.
Backup files are on NFS mount.
Total number of channels 11.
I tried to reduce the number of channels and set sqlnet.expire_time, I couldn't find any other information in the community. Especially nothing about seeing this error at the time of restore.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the NFS file system mounted and accessible? Have the NFS mount options been changed?

Comment: @pmdba Hello Pete. We found that our backup & storage team is due to file transfer with another tool. This is what caused the problem.